# Optimal brush advance map for large brushed DC motor with active advance control

Tags: dc-motor, brushed-dc-motor

I am posting here for advice as to the procedure to construct a map from motor speed and amps to advance for a Brushed DC electric motor with realtime, fast advance control.

I have built a Brushed DC electric sportscar with a 1000 amp output controller. The motor has a mobile brush carrier and a powerful and fast servo to provide continuous servo-driven advance from 5 to 15 degrees. See photo of the servo advance on http://thousand-amps.blogspot.com/ (just need to scroll down a bit). Current testing is with a fixed plate replacing the servo, at 5 degrees advance, as I wanted to take things one a time and these motors are known to work decently over a fairly wide RPM range with fixed advance. As expected the motor works very nicely with the fixed avance up to the speeds I have tested so far which are up to about 100 kph / 5000 RPM.

I want to create a 2 dimensional map that I can load into an arduino to control the servo. Inputs will be instantaneous motor amps and RPM, or motor amps and voltage. The output will be advance position for the servo.

What would the theory be as to the optimal advance as a function of load and RPM?
I have seen some discussion already of the subject of advance on this forum but always with the assumption that the advance is fixed, which leads to the conclusion "there is no optimal value". In my case, I think there is!

With many thanks in advance (no pun intended)

Comment: Why don't you use some form of commutator-spark optical feedback and use the control system to minimize that. After all, that is what you appear to be wanting to do.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought of that! And I could later remove the optical feedback system once I've set up the optimal map. Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered that the use of [interpoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armature_(electrical)#Armature_reaction_in_a_DC_machine) might be of some use. I'm assuming you are trying to extend the life of the brushes, yes?

Comment: It depends what you're optimising. Minimum sparking may not coincide with highest torque or greatest efficiency so the first thing you need is a definition of "optimal" (which may vary in different scenarios, e.g. acceleration, cruise, and you may need negative advance while braking.

Comment: Hi, no I am not trying to extend brush life as I will probably be putting very few miles on this car. Concerning interpoles, I'm not planning on modifying the motor, it was balanced and fitted with the variable timing lever by a very skilled DC motor expert so I'd rather keep it as is.

Comment: What I wish to optimize is efficiency, that is: find the setting of brush advance that produces maximum power output for a given input, for every load and speed combination. I don't think that definition varies for acceleration and cruise; in cruise the advance setting will be constant, and during acceleration it will vary, but since the motor doesn't have any memory and the servo is very fast, I don't think it matters - it's still a map with one single optimum value for each point in 2 dimensions.

Comment: One more question: can anyone tell me if there is a chance that near-optimal brush advance may be achieved mapping to RPM only and not to load? This would have a very good consequence for me, in that I could replace the fast rotary servo with a screw-type linear servo that is better suited to holding a fixed position for cruise.  Maybe someone who knows more about DC motors can tell me if, in theory, it's both load and rpm or only rpm that need to be accounted for?